# About choosing Data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, types

If in one of my columns in my Table I want the values as either Yes, No or Optional then what data type do I need to use?

Comment: A nullable bit would work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### BIT:

- takes 1 byte, but up to 8 BIT fields can be merged into a single BYTE in SQL Server.
- stores one of two values: 1 (meaning true) and 0 (meaning false) so the column needs to be nullable in order for NULL to pass as your third value

### CHAR(1)

- takes 1 byte
- 26 characters if case insensitive ASCII vs 52 if case sensitive

### TINYINT

- takes 1 byte
- values zero to 255

### Performance

All of the options take the same amount of space, making performance equivalent for JOINs/etc.

### Comparison

`BIT` is not the wisest choice if there's any chance of the possible values changing.  `CHAR(1)` is immediately readable IE: Y, N, O.  `TINYINT` is a good choice for the primary key in a table you want to relate via foreign key, and store the descriptive text in another column.

### Conclusion:

`CHAR(1)` would be my choice if not using a foreign key relationship, `TINYINT` otherwise.
With CHAR(1), having a natural primary key that is a single character is very unlikely.  Assuming a natural key based on the leading character fails if you have 2+ words that start with the same character, and causes grief if the label needs to change because the key should also change and be perpetuated (unless you're lazy & like explaining why a code doesn't follow the same scheme as the others).  CHAR(1) also provides roughly a fifth of the possibilities (assuming the upper end, 52 case sensitive values) that TINYINT does -- the artificial/surrogate key insulates from description changes.

Comment: Actually, BIT takes 1 byte - but up to 8 BIT fields can be merged into a single BYTE in SQL Server.

Comment: When using CHAR(1), remember to add a check constraint so that only the values you want can be put in the field. e.g. MyColumn IN('Y','N','O')

Comment: "TINYINT is a good choice for the primary key in a table you want to relate via foreign key, and store the descriptive text in another column" Why is CHAR(1) bad for the same?

Comment: @vgv8: I updated the conclusion to address the issue.  Neither is "bad", just that depending on business rules & use -- one is more prudent than the other.

Answer (score 3):

Use BIT for a True / False or in your case use CHAR(1) Y/N or CHAR(3) Yes / No.

Really I would use a CHAR(1) here because the extra 2 chars don't add any real value.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised to see so many votes for "Bit" here.  It's a bad choice.

Semantically, NULL means "unknown", so it's not a good choice as a third (known) value.  If you use it that way you can run into a lot of problems down the road.  For example, aggregate functions, GROUP BY, and joins may not behave the way you're expecting. User interfaces may not handle treating NULL as a value well either (MS Access has trouble with null bit fields, for example).  You'll also be unable to help preserve data integrity by defining the field NOT NULL.

Finally, you'll probably confuse any other database/application developer down the road who is used to the normal use of the value.

Go with the CHAR or TinyInt.

Answer (score 0):

Both Sergey and JonVD offer good solutions, but I'll agree with Sergey. A nullable bit offers your three options.  If it's not null, then you know the user took the option.

Comment: Additionally, you'll need to add a constraint onto a CHAR column to ensure that the values are only e.g. 'Y', 'N' or NULL, or risk some numpty throwing in random characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would use char(1) or an INT with a check constraint.
Just to minimize potential mismatches between the database and whatever abstraction layer you are using to access it. JDBC has no TINYINT for example.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the options "OMG Ponies" presents but not for his conclusion in this case.

Use the bit column!  Having a single bit assigned to hold the data gives one six other Y/N/O and a single Y/N storage locations for free.  When one uses the Bit data type always define at least on bit as non null so SQL will reserve a place in the data page for the values.